# Android chip text not showing

Tags: android, android-chips

There seems to be a bug in Android Material Design Chip: the chip text does not show when added in a RecyclerView item that's off the view port. When the RecyclerView is scrolled to show the item, the item's chip text is not visible, though the chip's color is correct. If the item is added to the RecyclerView within the view port, the chip text is visible, as expected.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                  android:id="@+id/chip"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  android:text="@{ obj.orderString() }"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                  app:status="@{ obj }"
                  android:textColor="@color/colorNeutral"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  app:chipStartPadding="@dimen/default_padding"
                  app:chipEndPadding="@dimen/default_padding"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                  android:enabled="false"
                  tools:text="1"
                  tools:checked="true"/>
```

Has anyone encountered something like this?

[image: chip text not visible]

Comment: your code works ok for me. maybe problem that no text is passed?

Answer (score 0):

set width and height TextView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_white"
    android:backgroundTint="#C72E00"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

background_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#f7f7f7" />
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks @armin-haghighi for the reply, but I'm using the Chip class, not a custom shape.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same id for you chips. Remove id and enjoy :)

Comment: Why do you say that this `android:id="@+id/chip"` would generate duplicate ids?